# Multiple images onmouseover, one by one.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make my logo static .png image, but when I put cursor over the logo, I want it to play "slideshow" of 7 images, changing one by one.

I know that I can achive this with code like this:

```
      <img src="image.png" onmouseover="this.src='image.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='image.png'" />
```

But I want something like this:

```
      <img src="image.png" onmouseover="this.src='image1.png/0.1s delay/image2.png/0.1s delay/image3.png/0.1s delay/'" onmouseout="this.src='image.png'" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, only you need to modify your approach a little bit. Consider this code:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/1" data-mouseover="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/2#500 http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/3#600 http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/4#300" />
```

and this JS to handle declared image sources:

```
$('img').on('mouseover', function() {
    var self = this,
        i = 0,
        images = $(this).data('mouseover').split(/\s+/);

    (function nextImage() {
        var next = images[i++ % images.length].split('#');
        $(self).data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
            self.src = next[0];
            nextImage();
        }, next[1] || 200));
    })();

}).on('mouseout', function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    this.src = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e2j1a6vt/

Comment: Thank You! But, both ideas are not working. Look at this: http://sedmica.rs/ I am trying to do this with my logo. Your js code is at the end of <head> tag.

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't implement it right. If you load script before respective HTML then wrap it in document ready. Then you also don't define timeout separated with `#` char. Here is improved version: http://jsfiddle.net/e2j1a6vt/1/ with default timeout 200ms if you don't specify you own.

Comment: Is it ok to put $('.image-class').on('mouseover'.... instead of img? 
I done everything else as you mentioned above, but... it's unchanged

Comment: Of course. You should use the selector which makes more sense to your situation. In your case probably `jQuery('#left_logo img')`.

Comment: Also I checked you site. Seems that you have jQuery no conflict mode. So change in my script `$` to `jQuery`.

Comment: Instead of each dollar sign or just instead of the first one?

Comment: It doesn't work because: 1. you have to use `jQuery` insetead of all `$` in my script. 2. Wrap the code into `jQuery(function() { /* the code i provided */ });`. 3. Use correct selector `jQuery('#left_logo img').on('mouseover` ...`. After above I can see that "7" changes nicely on hover.

Comment: I have a most beautiful logo in the world, and it's all because of You! Thank You very much :)

Comment: Hm.. Now, "mouse over" does not work. Animation starts, but never stops. :/ sorry

Comment: Make sure to replace `$` with `jQuery` here too: `clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));` and here `this.src = $(this).attr('src');`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of image sources and use them.

```
var counter = 0, arr = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png"];
$('img').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', function() {
        return arr[counter++];
    })
});
```